# ASP.net Web page is not carrying session variable in Chrome but carrying after response.write statement

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I have a webpage in ASP.net carrying session variable to another page, It is working for all browsers except chrome.

In chrome if I put `response.write` statement with some dummy test, it is carrying the variable, i changed session variable to query string but not solved.

i want to know what will be the problem.

Comment: Can you show your codes? Which Chrome version are you using?

Comment: please, add your session code...

Comment: the code is very simple,Session("corpid")=dr.item("CorpId"),response.redirect("booking.aspx?corpid=" & session("corpid") this is working fine in ie,safari,ff but not working in Chrome if I use response.write with dummy test ,then it is getting the value